# Ubuntu 16.04 two finger scroll problem

Tags: 16.04, dell, touchpad, scrolling

Recently I did a Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade on my Dell Inspiron - 5000 series.

After performing the upgrade I noticed the two finger scroll is not working any more.
The option in the settings menu is available and active but the two finger scroll does not work. The other mouse functions on the touchpad work though.

What is wrong here and how can I fix two finger scrolling again?

Comment: Does it work any better holding your fingers slightly apart?

Comment: Hi ubfan1,thanks for your comment. Holding the fingers more apart doesn't help anything unfortunately. Sometimes the scrolling works just a veeery little bit but not near as how it should be. Thanks in advance for your assistance! Kind regards

Comment: Just a follow up to see if and how this problem was solved. Also I posted an answer today which you may have tried already but could update in your question as having tried: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/833112/touchpad-two-finger-scroll-not-working/833153#833153]